# SVN user groups and permissions

Tags: svn, permissions, tortoisesvn, ssh, usergroups

I have setup an SVN server on my hosting account. Users can check in and out, but they have access to my entire repository.

To give people access, I issue users a public key to my account and then I add a line into my "authorized_keys" file inside my ~/.ssh that looks like this:

```
command="/home/user/packages/bin/svnserve -t -r /home/user/repository --tunnel-user=diogo",no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa [KEY DATA IN HERE]== xxxx@xxxx.hostxxxxx.com
```

Users can then checkout from my sever through a tunnel like so:

```
svn+ssh://host.com/project/trunk
```

My question is how can I restrict certain users to have access to certain projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a SSH tunnel. If I read the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html) correctly, you will need to set the permissions on the repository files themselves for the user you log in as, but you can also block users directly in the conf file:

> When running over a tunnel, authorization is primarily controlled by operating system permissions to the repository's database files; it's very much the same as if Harry were accessing the repository directly via a file:/// URL.
>
> If multiple system users are going to be accessing the repository directly, you may want to place them into a common group, and you'll need to be careful about umasks. (Be sure to read the section called “Supporting Multiple Repository Access Methods”.)
>
> But even in the case of tunneling, the svnserve.conf file can still be used to block access, by simply setting auth-access = read or auth-access = none.

(From "SSH authentication and authorization")

By the way, you say you are doing this on your hosting account. I tried that as well once, but had to give up because I was not allowed to add new SSH users. If you can't add SSH user accounts, you can't do fine-grained authentication through a tunnel - users will always have full access to the repo.

To use multi-user authentication independently from SSH, you'd have to integrate svn with Apache, something that's usually impossible in a shared environment.

I ended up switching to a small Windows-based virtual server and installing Brain-dead easy svn wrapper [VisualSVN Server](http://visualsvn.com/) there. It costs some money (about €20/month, I've seen Linux based virtual servers starting at $10) but I've been happy with it ever since. (Of course, you can just use Linux and set up svn with Apache, which is what VisualSVN does internally too.)

Comment: My hosting account is through hostmonster so they only provide a single user login, therefore I won't be able to set user permissions on files as there is only 1 user. Is there any other way, or perhaps a way to add new users? Thanks

Comment: @Martin I don't think there is a way to add new users if your provider doesn't allow you to. These are user accounts on system level.

Comment: Yes, I've looked into integrating svn with Apache but I can't get access to certain files and cmds, hostmonster support said that would not be allowed. Anyway, I will look at other hosting providers in future then. Thanks for your help.